# SQL - Permutations excluding duplicates

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL server, I'm trying to write a T-SQL, on the table as below:
For each of the TS_Variables, I need a combination of other TS_Variables(each values) i.e., Master-forward-Individual
And I dont want to see repetitions for "Master-forward-Individual", like "forward-Master-Individual", "Individual-forward-Master".
Please help me write a sql statement such that i get the required output as shown below.

Sub_Process_ID  TS_Variables    TS_Values

ACT.1.1     Company     Master
ACT.1.1     Company     Branch
ACT.1.1     Value Date  Forward
ACT.1.1     Value Date  Current
ACT.1.1     Value Date  Back
ACT.1.1     Customer    Individual

ACT.1.1     Customer    Joint
ACT.1.2     Company     Master
ACT.1.2      Company    Branch
ACT.1.2     Value Date  Forward
ACT.1.2     Value Date  Current
ACT.1.2     Value Date  Back
ACT.1.2     Customer    Individual
ACT.1.2     Customer    Joint
ACT.1.2     Customer    Minor

Required Output:

Sub_Process_ID  TS_Values   TS_Values   TS_Values

ACT.1.1     Branch      Back        Individual

ACT.1.1     Branch      Back        Joint

ACT.1.1     Branch      Current     Individual

ACT.1.1     Branch      Current     Joint

ACT.1.1     Branch      Forward     Individual

ACT.1.1     Branch      Forward     Joint
ACT.1.1     Branch      Individual  Back
ACT.1.1     Branch      Individual  Current
ACT.1.1     Branch      Individual  Forward
ACT.1.1     Branch      Joint       Back
ACT.1.1     Branch      Joint       Current
ACT.1.1     Branch      Joint       Forward

ACT.1.1     Master      Back        Individual

ACT.1.1     Master      Back        Joint

ACT.1.1     Master      Current     Individual

ACT.1.1     Master      Current     Joint

ACT.1.1     Master      Forward     Individual

ACT.1.1     Master      Forward     Joint
ACT.1.1     Master      Individual  Back
ACT.1.1     Master      Individual  Current
ACT.1.1     Master      Individual  Forward
ACT.1.1     Master      Joint       Back
ACT.1.1     Master      Joint       Current
ACT.1.1     Master      Joint       Forward

Incorrect output, when i used join

Sub_Process_ID  TS_Values   TS_Values   TS_Values

ACT.1.1     Back        Branch      Individual
ACT.1.1     Back        Branch      Joint
ACT.1.1     Back        Individual  Branch
ACT.1.1     Back        Individual  Master
ACT.1.1     Back        Joint       Branch
ACT.1.1     Back        Joint       Master
ACT.1.1     Back        Master      Individual
ACT.1.1     Back        Master      Joint
ACT.1.1     Branch      Back        Individual
ACT.1.1     Branch      Back        Joint
ACT.1.1     Branch      Current     Individual
ACT.1.1     Branch      Current     Joint
ACT.1.1     Branch      Forward     Individual
ACT.1.1     Branch      Forward     Joint
ACT.1.1     Branch      Individual  Back
ACT.1.1     Branch      Individual  Current
ACT.1.1     Branch      Individual  Forward
ACT.1.1     Branch      Joint       Back
ACT.1.1     Branch      Joint       Current
ACT.1.1     Branch      Joint       Forward
ACT.1.1     Current     Branch      Individual
ACT.1.1     Current     Branch      Joint
ACT.1.1     Current     Individual  Branch
ACT.1.1     Current     Individual  Master
ACT.1.1     Current     Joint       Branch
ACT.1.1     Current     Joint       Master
ACT.1.1     Current     Master      Individual
ACT.1.1     Current     Master      Joint
ACT.1.1     Forward     Branch      Individual
ACT.1.1     Forward     Branch      Joint
ACT.1.1     Forward     Individual  Branch
ACT.1.1     Forward     Individual  Master
ACT.1.1     Forward     Joint       Branch
ACT.1.1     Forward     Joint       Master
ACT.1.1     Forward     Master      Individual
ACT.1.1     Forward     Master      Joint
ACT.1.1     Individual  Back        Branch
ACT.1.1     Individual  Back        Master
ACT.1.1     Individual  Branch      Back
ACT.1.1     Individual  Branch      Current
ACT.1.1     Individual  Branch      Forward
ACT.1.1     Individual  Current     Branch
ACT.1.1     Individual  Current     Master
ACT.1.1     Individual  Forward     Branch
ACT.1.1     Individual  Forward     Master
ACT.1.1     Individual  Master      Back
ACT.1.1     Individual  Master      Current
ACT.1.1     Individual  Master      Forward
ACT.1.1     Joint       Back        Branch
ACT.1.1     Joint       Back        Master
ACT.1.1     Joint       Branch      Back
ACT.1.1     Joint       Branch      Current
ACT.1.1     Joint       Branch      Forward
ACT.1.1     Joint       Current     Branch
ACT.1.1     Joint       Current     Master
ACT.1.1     Joint       Forward     Branch
ACT.1.1     Joint       Forward     Master
ACT.1.1     Joint       Master      Back
ACT.1.1     Joint       Master      Current
ACT.1.1     Joint       Master      Forward
ACT.1.1     Master      Back        Individual
ACT.1.1     Master      Back        Joint
ACT.1.1     Master      Current     Individual
ACT.1.1     Master      Current     Joint
ACT.1.1     Master      Forward     Individual
ACT.1.1     Master      Forward     Joint
ACT.1.1     Master      Individual  Back
ACT.1.1     Master      Individual  Current
ACT.1.1     Master      Individual  Forward
ACT.1.1     Master      Joint       Back
ACT.1.1     Master      Joint       Current
ACT.1.1     Master      Joint       Forward

Comment: Edit your question and show your query.